# Angular radio button in Syncfusion grid is not persisting its selection

Tags: angular, grid, radio-button, syncfusion

I have a Boolean radio button column in an Angular SyncFusion grid.

```
<e-column field='IsPrivate' headerText='Private/Business' [template]="radioButton" width="180">
    <ng-template #radioButton let-trip >
        <ejs-radiobutton label="Private" name="trip.TripId"></ejs-radiobutton> &nbsp;
        <ejs-radiobutton label="Business" name="trip.TripId" checked="trip.IsBusiness"></ejs-radiobutton>
    </ng-template>
</e-column>
```

The problem is that the radio buttons don't persist their selection across rows (i.e. a selection in row one will be affected when a selection in row two or three etc is made). How can I make each selection independent to the row in the grid?

Answer (score 0):

I was not interpolating the `name` attribute correctly.

```
name="{{trip.TripId}}"
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. We have to give unique value for name attribute to persist radio button selection on each row. get back to us if you require further assistance